# iOS code leaks in one application but not in another

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, alassetslibrary

Hi I have been trying to track down a very elusive memory leak in my application.

In an attempt to isolate the cause I have pared back the leaking code and even moved it to the app delegate for test purposes to try to eliminate as many factors as possible.

The following code is called from did finish launching with options.

```
- (void)loadDataAsTest {


        NSLog(@"%s ", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

        _library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

        [_library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *alAssetsGroup, BOOL *stop) {

            @autoreleasepool {

                if (alAssetsGroup) {

                    [alAssetsGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *st) {
                        @autoreleasepool {

                            if (alAsset) {

                                NSLog(@"index = %u", index);
                                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[alAsset thumbnail]];

                            }
                            else {


                            }
                        }
                    }];
                }
            }

        }                     failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {

        }];

}
```

In my application this code leaks about 2000 CGImage enumerating over the 1000 photos in the photo stream. All 2000 UIImages that are created are released ok.

If I create a new empty project for testing purposes and put the same code in the app delegate and call it in exactly the same way it does not leak. All CGimage are released and all UIImage are released again about 2000 instances of each.

Both projects are using ARC.

Why would the same code called in exactly the same way behave differently between two projects?

Comment: Do you have `NSZombieEnabled` set in one project?

Comment: Doesnt appear to be enabled in either if I check on the edit scheme diagnostics tab. Is there any other way they could be enabled?